# How to make IIS application access network through http proxy

Tags: iis, proxy

I have an IIS application server in China, but one of our applications is access Salesforce soap api and it is too slow now. I want make this application access network via http proxy. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You would use the WebProxy class from .net

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webproxy(v=vs.110).aspx

```
WebProxy proxyObject = new WebProxy("http://proxyserver:80/",true);
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com");
req.Proxy = proxyObject;
```

Comment: Hi Henry, we are using soap api to connect salesforce api and is there any IIS configuration that can let us to use the proxy?